# wget and ssl downloads over proxy

Tags: wget, ssl

whenever I try to download a https page using wget over a proxy I get the following error `Proxy tunneling failed: Bad RequestUnable to establish SSL connection.` there is a launchpad bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget/+bug/994097 but like many such bugs it is drifting in limbo.

Can anyone help me debug the issue? Where should I even begin to try

a) find out what the problem is and

b) develop a patch to fix it

I want to learn to make useful submissions to help but I don't know how.. any help will be appreciated.